# Continuous spikes in Request Time and Search Latency in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have noticed continuous spikes with 1min interval in both **RequestTime** and **SearchLatency** graphs for Elastic Search.

Related spikes are also observed for **Latency** in all ES data nodes.
We are using ElasticSearch v5.6.3 and Kibana v6.1.3.

Here are the graphs captured from kibana:

- Request time for Index:
  [image: Request time for Index]
- Search Latency for Index:
  [image: Search Latency for Index]
- Latency on a ES node:
  [image: Latency on a ES node]
  We are researching over internal operations performed by ES, like segment merging, etc, from 2-3 days. Also, there isn't any recent changes rolled out, which would impact ES.

These spikes are impacting our application's search response times.

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome?

Comment: facing same issue, spikes every minute latency...
not sure how to fix it?
any idea for now?

Comment: Check if any recent changes were made to kind of data or ingestion configuration.. Also, notice since when spikes started coming.

Answer (score 0):

After continuous investigation, I have found a probable cause for such spikes.
These spikes were related to the background tasks performed by elastic search for its internal management of indexes.

Our team recently added a `nested field` in the document with 'include_in_parent' property set to true. This property helps to index inner/nested objects as nested field and as well as flattened field.

While testing out possible fixes, after removing the nested field, we didn't notice the spikes. Later on, we added same fields as 'flattened' field, which worked fine.

**Note**: We could have resolved this earlier. But, we weren't sure whether these spikes were there prior to adding nested field. This is because,

> Kibana only keeps the monitoring information for last 1 week

, and not more than that.